# How to Decipher an SDR File

Tags: land-survey

I want to create a custom import routine that can read/import an sdr file. The sdr files will contain information the surveyor has picked up when completing an as-built. The data will likely contain info on sewer lines and manholes etc... I need to read the file and convert it to more readable form extracting XY coordinates.

I am new to sdr files and I have looked online but as yet cannot find anywhere that explains the different parts to the file.

The file is an ascii text file but the text is a bit cryptic to me. Can someone help me understand how to read the file?

I have included the file here and I don't expect someone to go line by line but if you could grab a section and say what it is doing and how to get usable information from it? What I need is Cartesian coordinates and an understanding of what data the file has recorded.

I hope I have explained enough to give you an understanding of what I am after.

Here is the file I was given as an example:

> 00NMSDR20     V03-05    19-May-15 13:16 113111 10NM18TH 19MAY15
>   13CPSea level crn: N                                             13CPC
>   and R crn: N                                               13CPAtmos
>   crn: N                                                 06NM1.00000000
>   13OOCurrent view
>   13TS19-May-15 11:14
>   13JS10000
>   13TS19-May-15 11:15
>   08KI0001805555.619372578.52060.2780000IS 1
>   08KI1000805506.488372503.18362.6710000CHK2             13TS19-May-15
>   11:30                                              01NM:SET3030R3
>   035653                00000031                    0.00000000
>   13PCReflector type: Sheet
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   02TP0001805555.619372578.52060.27800001.51300000IS 1
>   13PCReflector type: Prism
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: -30.000
>   13TLEDM tol. error:  Pt: 1000 0.029
>   13TLV.obs tol. error:  Pt: 1000 0-01'24"
>   07TP00011000236.889632236.889722 03NM1.50300000
>   09F10001100090.001998388.5055555236.889722CHK2
>   09F10001000290.001998388.5058333236.890000IS 2
>   13PCReflector type: None
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   03NM0.00000000 09F10001100133.159003595.372500023.9275000B CL
>   13TS19-May-15 11:40
>   09F10001100223.081999796.484722215.8830555CL
>   09F10001100314.637995698.2472222359.583333CL
>   09F10001100412.278006499.0144444348.680000CL
>   09F10001100541.929008194.756944428.9430555B LLL
>   09F10001100633.127995495.406666625.3286111LLL
>   09F10001100723.073007296.526388817.2686111LLL
>   09F10001100814.671002098.25000000.02972222LLL
>   09F10001100942.545005094.700000025.9958333B LLR
>   09F10001101033.449000095.343055522.5869444LLR
>   09F10001101123.333993896.433888815.3083333LLR
>   09F10001101214.734000698.2108333359.618333LLR
>   13PCReflector type: Sheet
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   13PCReflector type: None
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   09F10001101341.842994894.901666633.5125000B ELL
>   09F10001101432.460007895.629722230.7866666ELL
>   09F10001101522.093007596.983055524.6222222ELL
>   09F10001101614.125997199.069444412.8650000ELL
>   09F10001101710.1820014101.169722359.147777ELL
>   09F10001101842.080001494.726666627.8213888ESI
>   09F10001101942.081000594.733888828.3241666ESI
>   09F10001102042.490999094.716666628.8533333ESI
>   09F10001102144.815001194.580277729.4322222ESI
>   09F10001102246.794001694.473055529.8577777ESI
>   13PCReflector type: Sheet
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   03NM1.94500000 09F10001102346.803993392.083611129.7355555ESI
>   09F10001102446.886992292.071944427.4763888ESI
>   09F10001102543.960998592.069444427.0383333ESI
>   09F10001102642.305000992.069444427.2433333ESI
>   09F10001102741.612000292.390833335.5294444B ESL
>   09F10001102841.510999392.286666635.8852777B TKL
>   09F10001102931.509001093.195277735.2919444B XNG
>   13TS19-May-15 11:51
>   03NM1.44500000 09F10001103031.393994893.120555536.8958333XNG
>   09F10001103127.606005293.229166636.4225000XNG
>   09F10001103227.439008393.278055534.0844444XNG
>   09F10001103326.797998393.272222234.7058333PP
>   09F10001103430.565005393.343888833.8358333ESL
>   09F10001103526.800995893.299166633.7438888TKL
>   09F10001103619.977002293.492500031.5122222TKL
>   09F10001103719.957001893.491944431.5183333B XNG
>   09F10001103821.144998293.632777731.0744444ESL
>   09F10001103920.142000793.456111133.5150000XNG
>   09F10001104020.134007393.456111133.5183333B FPP
>   09F10001104123.932005693.366111135.3563888XNG
>   09F10001104224.239004993.361388833.2975000XNG
>   09F10001104324.238005793.361388833.2933333TKX
>   09F10001104414.250994993.475555532.5841666FPP
>   09F10001104513.956002693.540833332.2211111B XNG
>   09F10001104614.667005493.659444428.1775000XNG
>   09F10001104714.666006293.659444428.1683333TKL
>   09F10001104814.302003493.998055527.8288888XNG
>   09F1000110495.8480075995.21500005.86944444XNG
>   09F1000110505.6329997194.29555554.58805556XNG
>   09F1000110515.6440075294.29583334.52611111B TKL
>   09F1000110525.9570018194.76027771.90194444ESL
>   09F1000110535.2630019195.7308333356.558055CP
>   09F1000110545.2449999294.5655555350.491666WL
>   09F1000110555.2180053994.424166615.5508333XNG
>   13PCReflector type: None
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   03NM0.00000000 09F1000110565.55000085109.601388349.831666B WL
>   09F1000110576.73799726105.351111341.740833WL
>   09F1000110585.42800047109.86388815.7680555FPP
>   09F1000110596.27600806103.933055289.974444WL
>   09F1000110607.19500754101.957222294.291666ELL
>   09F10001106110.089993198.0530555296.649444CL
>   09F1000110629.4989923697.5808333259.249722WL
>   09F1000110639.0190011798.1822222254.804722WL
>   09F1000110648.5929990398.9980555249.535833WL
>   09F10001106514.604006893.7686111249.677777ELL
>   09F10001106615.978001393.2552777259.905555CL
>   13PCReflector type: Sheet
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   03NM1.94500000 09F10001106743.225998792.164444421.6475000B ELR
>   09F10001106843.906992592.185277719.6688888B TKR
>   09F10001106943.726007292.304166619.9713888B ESR
>   09F10001107041.945994092.177500018.5208333B XNG
>   09F10001107142.360006192.035000017.0791666XNG
>   13TS19-May-15 12:01
>   09F10001107238.183000692.054166614.5211111XNG
>   09F10001107337.653999292.128055516.0850000XNG
>   09F10001107435.105996792.069444414.2933333TKR
>   09F10001107534.945994092.197777714.7491666ESR
>   09F10001107634.241003292.037222217.4558333ELR
>   09F10001107728.694999191.877500010.1497222B LBR
>   09F10001107828.192992391.83166667.15055556B XNG
>   09F10001107924.416992791.63805559.42305556ELR
>   09F10001108025.510000291.69694446.27277778LBR
>   09F10001108124.470998791.77222222.32444444ESR
>   09F10001108228.771003791.69777775.26416667XNG
>   09F10001108325.502006891.5175000359.709444XNG
>   09F10001108425.489999891.5141666359.698611B FPL
>   09F10001108524.570001291.62500001.47666667XNG
>   09F10001108624.556995091.62388881.48972222TKR
>   09F10001108720.960998591.32750000.35305556B WL
>   09F10001108821.986993991.5936111357.339166WLX
>   09F10001108919.192992391.15000000.33833333ELR
>   09F10001109014.539992290.1091666341.607777ELR
>   09F10001109115.880997190.0500000327.598333WLX
>   09F10001109214.405002689.6725000329.373333WL
>   09F10001109318.678995491.1005555346.305000ESR
>   09F10001109418.889007490.8638888345.476944TKR
>   09F10001109516.087994789.7063888323.971944TKR
>   09F10001109615.766007989.9180555324.066944ESR
>   09F10001109714.872004689.5741666324.222222LBR
>   09F10001109822.649003489.7705555341.873333TREE 2
>   09F10001109926.456993391.3744444357.667500B FPR
>   09F10001110030.258006190.2177777350.316388XNGX
>   09F10001110127.451997589.9772222351.126388SH
>   09F10001110220.974004688.7627777321.126944SH
>   09F10001110318.487002389.3377777319.695277B EM
>   09F10001110423.829006489.0938888316.936111EM
>   09F10001110523.452996789.0280555308.471111EM
>   09F10001110618.360006188.7191666308.784166EM
>   13TS19-May-15 12:11
>   09F10001110718.328998088.7258333308.784444FPR
>   09F10001110817.052007788.7947222308.009722FPL
>   09F10001110917.022997888.7927777308.024166B XNG
>   09F10001111015.983996388.8311111307.482222XNG
>   09F10001111116.145997489.7200000323.371388B XNG
>   09F10001111217.168995289.5861111322.547222XNG
>   09F10001111312.981998087.7800000297.573888ELR
>   09F10001111415.170993688.3916666299.350277LBR
>   09F10001111514.136005788.0825000298.333888B WL
>   09F10001111615.678995489.0286111302.538888CP
>   09F10001111715.838998188.6991666299.140000ESR
>   09F10001111816.123998788.4288888299.815277TKR
>   09F10001111923.022997887.6027777304.675000B LB
>   09F10001112020.711002787.6038888304.235277LB
>   09F10001112123.788006686.9247222281.477777LB
>   09F10001112222.445003387.4125000277.427777B XNG
>   09F10001112318.068993586.8086111266.668888ELR
>   09F10001112417.108994287.2100000275.740555WL
>   09F10001112519.469000387.2002777270.673888LBR
>   09F10001112619.154007787.6294444275.948333ESR
>   09F10001112719.506003587.5497222276.732777TKR
>   09F10001112824.701993386.8077777280.564166B XNG
>   09F10001112926.579992986.8750000282.688333XNG
>   09F10001113025.624007287.0825000285.250000TD
>   13PCReflector type: None
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   09F10001113115.385002393.6944444236.986388B WLA
>   03NM0.00000000 09F10001113215.911006193.2230555243.305833WLA
>   09F10001113322.706006991.3561111236.994444WLA
>   09F10001113424.674998790.9438888245.691388CL
>   09F10001113534.188995689.8719444239.320555CL
>   09F10001113624.222002191.0483333238.725555ELL
>   13TS19-May-15 12:21
>   13PCReflector type: Sheet
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   03NM1.94500000 09F10001113725.449999287.0138888286.797500WM
>   09F10001113820.598994187.5100000277.375277B XNG
>   09F10001113919.579992987.5602777276.574444XNG
>   09F10001114022.915002887.2108333266.209444B XNG
>   09F10001114123.454995087.2716666268.726111XNG
>   09F10001114227.063997786.7413888277.058611B LB
>   09F10001114325.879998086.8016666275.316666LB
>   09F10001114433.776998886.4183333259.748888LB
>   09F10001114534.970008086.4066666261.641666SH
>   03NM0.30000000 09F10001114636.877000588.7647222258.356111TREE 3
>   03NM1.94500000 09F10001114723.489999887.2663888268.828333FPL
>   09F10001114827.300005186.9388888279.148055B XNG
>   09F10001114925.545005086.8744444276.843888XNG
>   09F10001115023.583007387.3241666273.765000XNG
>   09F10001115124.425003087.2347222270.843055FPR
>   09F10001115223.593998286.9186111258.724722B WL
>   09F10001115332.488001586.9136111248.177222WL
>   09F10001115436.486003187.1222222247.925000ESR
>   09F10001115534.976003087.0169444249.713333TKR
>   09F10001115634.963996087.0152777249.720833B XNG
>   09F10001115735.871005486.9975000250.955555XNG
>   09F10001115839.228996386.9983333248.583333FPL
>   09F10001115939.235008286.9997222248.580000B XNG
>   09F10001116038.905993387.0225000247.011666XNG
>   09F10001116135.335992186.8047222243.679444ELR
>   09F10001116239.818997886.9783333250.177500FPR
>   09F10001116339.799996686.9758333250.185555B XNG            13OS41.800 
>   86-31'34"           252-14'01"          OS 1.500   13OSDirn <
>   09F10001116441.826901886.5283484254.292578XNG              13OS39.347 
>   86-20'49"           252-52'13"          OS 2.000   13OSDirn <
>   09F10001116539.397797086.3516608255.786020XNG
>   13TS19-May-15 12:31
>   09F10001116637.637995686.9805555252.087777XNG
>   09F10001116743.059001886.2522222252.643611B TBL
>   09F10001116844.817998686.2741666249.666666TBL
>   09F10001116947.007993486.2980555248.369722TBL
>   09F10001117047.008992586.2977777248.361388B HDG SHRUBS
>   09F10001117147.285000686.2044444249.178055TREE 5
>   09F10001117245.860996886.2500000249.379722WM
>   09F10001117340.332994686.9727777247.123333SIGN BUS
>   09F10001117440.371996187.0344444246.163611B FPB
>   09F10001117540.779996387.0355555247.406666FPB
>   09F10001117642.164998687.0522222246.607777B FPB
>   09F10001117741.693999987.0525000245.418888FPB
>   09F10001117839.327998887.0036111244.428888B YL
>   09F10001117936.196006787.0308333247.046111LBR
>   09F10001118038.817998686.8866666242.681666YL
>   03NM2.44500000 09F10001118152.632000585.9336111245.755000HDG
>   13OS52.448    86-03'40"           245-13'42"          OS 1.000
>   13OSDirn <
>   09F10001118252.457533286.0618280246.323216B FLR
>   03NM1.94500000 09F10001118350.895002587.1850000241.820833LP
>   13PCReflector type: Prism
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: -30.000
>   03NM1.50300000 09F10001118490.000999288.5055555236.879722CHK2
>   13PCReflector type: None
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   13TS19-May-15 12:43
>   03NM0.00000000 09F10001118526.979000590.6816666234.774444WLA
>   09F10001118626.638994790.9125000231.091388WLA
>   09F10001118733.582008289.9630555234.392500ELL
>   09F10001118832.580992190.2444444229.653333B YL
>   09F10001118932.728005690.1100000231.505000YL
>   09F10001119032.981998090.0319444233.918333YL BUS
>   09F10001119140.871005489.5508333231.868333YL
>   09F10001119247.427001389.3091666230.636111YL
>   09F10001119345.325001389.3647222231.414444ELL
>   09F10001119434.188995689.8755555239.313333CLX
>   09F10001119539.704008589.5247222236.993055CL
>   09F10001119642.859997689.3863888235.966388CL
>   09F10001119745.728005689.2958333235.135000CL
>   09F10001119848.931006589.2102777234.327500CL
>   09F10001119947.383003989.3797222228.826944YL
>   09F10001120047.285000689.4675000227.856388YL
>   09F10001120147.700994189.3794444228.749444B LLC
>   09F10001120251.106995989.3044444228.302222LLC
>   09F10001120352.918000389.2972222228.071944LLC
>   09F10001120456.615996989.2461111227.723333LLC
>   13PCReflector type: Sheet
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   13PCReflector type: Prism
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: -30.000
>   13PCReflector type: None
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   09F10001120533.612999489.9611111234.388888ELX
>   09F10001120640.120002089.5672222232.520000ELL
>   09F10001120745.284001489.3652777231.427777ELL
>   09F10001120849.051008589.2619444230.760555ELL
>   09F10001120951.388999089.2258333230.394722ELL
>   09F10001121053.218005489.2027777230.094166ELL
>   13PCReflector type: Sheet
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: 0.000
>   13TS19-May-15 12:54
>   03NM1.44500000 09F10001005060.883994687.4333333219.972500NAIL
>   09F1000112114.7579976094.267222230.3730555B FPA
>   09F1000112122.9229961694.840555525.4622222SWMH
>   09F1000112131.3469999590.080277764.3483333TREE 6
>   09F1000112142.8550017893.4422222332.569444SIGN SCHOOL
>   09F10001121510.277007288.5713888242.095277B XNG
>   09F10001121610.134007388.2911111235.568333XNG
>   09F1000112179.9720063087.8613888226.963055B XNG
>   09F1000112189.9740046487.9016666227.464444FPA
>   09F10001121911.889007487.8763888226.221111FPA
>   09F10001122013.658995187.8458333223.974166FPA
>   09F10001122113.566004587.9294444232.067777FPP
>   09F10001122213.885993087.7833333229.216388FPP
>   09F10001122315.612000287.5433333226.138055FPP
>   09F10001122411.933004888.3944444189.565555XNG
>   09F10001122514.255008688.6116666194.801111XNG
>   09F10001122615.035004887.5238888195.516666FLX
>   09F10001122714.704008587.5316666216.928888SH
>   09F10001122816.983996387.5400000217.312500TREE 5
>   09F10001122913.633998987.8519444223.436944XNG
>   09F10001123014.850005987.6186111222.147222FPA
>   09F10001123116.741993987.5022222220.876388FPA
>   09F10001123217.171992887.4811111225.431666FPP
>   09F10001123317.426002187.5738888226.248055PP
>   09F10001123415.593998288.1077777240.064166B LBL
>   09F10001123514.492997388.3719444237.856666ESL
>   09F10001123614.530000588.0963888236.375277TKL
>   09F10001123726.756998487.6688888232.865000LBL
>   09F10001123832.684008287.5836111231.202500LBL
>   09F10001123933.008992587.7052777229.462777ESL
>   09F10001124033.003996787.5802777228.901666TKL
>   09F10001124134.524005587.1883333224.292500FPP
>   09F10001124234.629003087.1150000222.153888FPA
>   09F10001124335.646005986.8113888218.603055TREE 6
>   09F10001124420.835001486.9816666205.123888B BEL
>   13TS19-May-15 13:04
>   09F10001124522.125997187.3013888211.260555BEL              13OS22.251 
>   86-54'16"           211-21'36"          OS 2.000   13OSDirn >
>   09F10001124622.340697786.9168858206.216384TREE 2           13OS28.368 
>   86-41'30"           215-45'33"          OS 2.000   13OSDirn >
>   09F10001124728.438414086.6998673211.719664TREE 2
>   09F10001124827.211993486.8908333211.730000B BEL
>   09F10001124927.841995687.0955555215.432777BEL
>   09F10001125033.776998886.8905555218.392777BEL
>   09F10001125144.974004687.6080555227.251944B FBB
>   09F10001125244.885993087.3291666224.261666FPB
>   09F10001125346.802994187.3825000224.171666FPB
>   09F10001125446.921997087.5055555225.710000SIGN BUS
>   09F10001125546.847008487.6177777227.087222FPB
>   09F10001125645.033006587.6141666228.985000LBL
>   09F10001125747.271994487.6327777228.671666LBL
>   09F10001125844.774001387.7283333227.816111ESL
>   09F10001125944.759995987.6144444227.461388TKL
>   09F10001126052.424003887.3905555221.979166PP
>   09F10001126148.930007387.3572222222.500555FPA
>   09F10001126248.889007487.4150000224.034444FPP
>   03NM1.94500000 09F10001126346.709004487.0075000238.657222ELR
>   09F10001126447.488001587.2133333241.981388ESR
>   09F10001126547.480008187.1300000242.416388TKR
>   09F10001126646.853003487.0305555239.091111YLX
>   09F10001126751.795999987.1441666237.532500YLX
>   09F10001126852.463005387.3013888240.022500YLX
>   09F10001126951.754000987.1311111237.148888ELR
>   13PCReflector type: Prism
>   13PCP.C. mm Applied: -30.000

Comment: If you have the opportunity to create a file yourself from surveying, do that. Write down everything you do, including timestamps. That way you have both sides of the reverse engineering process instead of needing to guess what's what.

Comment: Actually, did you see http://wikinova.info/doku.php/en:np:survey:menu:extensionsokkia:sokkia_methodiek ?

Comment: sweet! i made it an answer, so this question can be "solved"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is called "Sokkia SDR", that should make searching for references easier. You can find documentation of the format on http://wikinova.info/doku.php/en:np:survey:menu:extensionsokkia:sokkia_methodiek

Comment: Link is dead/down. See also https://github.com/r-barnes/sdr33_triangulation